# How to remove elements from FormArray in a loop in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have to remove multiple elements from `FormArray` in angular. The scenario is that every time i will have an array of indexes for which records to be deleted from the `FormArray`.

Like if have array of `FormArray` like this

```
const formArray = new FormArray([
  new FormControl(),
  new FormControl(),
  new FormControl(),
  new FormControl(),
  new FormControl()
]);
```

and let say i have an array of indexes of items that have to be deleted from the `FormArray` like this

```
const arrayOfItemIndexHaveToBeDeleted = [0,1,3,4];
```

I have tried this code

```
arrayOfItemIndexHaveToBeDeleted.reverse().forEach((index: number) => formArray.removeAt(index));
```

but this only works when index are consecutive. It is not working when indexes are not consecutive. Like i mentioned above. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can sort your indexes first to guarantee they are in the right order.

Comment: You can see that my array is already in sort order. But the problem is to remove elements from `FormArray` if the indexes in the array are not consecutive.

Comment: I don't understand. The indexes in the array would be consecutive *if* you sort them, right?

Comment: Let me rephrase my point. Every time i will be having an array with different indexes(it's not compulsory that indexes are consecutive). That means the indexes whose element have to deleted from the `FormArray` might not be in consucitive order. Like sometime i might have the indexes [4,3,1,0]. You see that `2` index is missing. It's not consecutive. So in this case it's not working

Comment: Ah, misunderstanding on my part what the word "consecutive" means :) sorry

Comment: What means "not working"? Controls are not removed at all?

Comment: Yeah, if indexes are not consecutive, then no elements is removing